# <input type="number"> doesn't seem to work with large numbers

Tags: javascript, input, numbers

Having this code:

```
  <form id="filterprice" method=get onsubmit="window.location = 'catalog/{$category->url}{if $brand}/{$brand->url}{/if}?price_min='+price_min.value+'&price_max='+price_max.value;return false;">
    <input type="number" id="price_min" name="price_min" min="0" onchange="check_min()" value={$price_min}> - <input type="number" id="price_max" name="price_max" min={$price_min} value={$price_max}>
    <input type="submit" value="Подобрать">
  </form>

<script>
  function check_min() {
  document.getElementById('price_max').min=document.getElementById('price_min').value;
    if(document.getElementById('price_max').min > document.getElementById('price_max').value) {
      document.getElementById('price_max').value=document.getElementById('price_max').min;
    }
  }
</script>
```

I.e. i have value 40000 in "price_min" and 40001000 in "price_max". The script sets "min" attribute of "price_max" to current value of "price_min" whenever i change the last one. So if i change "price_min" to 40002 the "min" attribute of "price_max" is set to 40002. But it also sets current value of "price_max" to 40002. Seems like it just trunks 3 digits of "price_max". Not to mention the "value" attribute of these `<input>` tags doesn't change even though I can change them at the page.
So the question is: are there any restrictions for the value of `<input type="number">`? Why does it work incorrectly when it comes to large numbers? Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the greater than check is on strings and not numbers. So you need to convert them to numbers.

```js
function check_min() {
  document.getElementById('price_max').min = document.getElementById('price_min').value;
  
  
  if (Number(document.getElementById('price_max').min) > Number(document.getElementById('price_max').value)) {
    document.getElementById('price_max').value = document.getElementById('price_max').min;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="filterprice" method=get>
  <input type="number" id="price_min" name="price_min" min="0" onchange="check_min()" value="123">-
  <input type="number" id="price_max" name="price_max" value="40001000">
  <input type="submit" value="Подобрать">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the values you get from `.min` and/or `.value` are strings and lexical comparison from `"40000"` and `"40001000"` makes `"40000"` be bigger.

Just use `if(parseInt(document.getElementById('price_max').min) > parseInt(document.getElementById('price_max').value).)`

Answer (score -1):

By giving default value to "price_min" and "price_max", the code works correctly.[jsFiddle code](https://fiddle.jshell.net/6ghnj0or/)

Comment: I doubt that is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Yep. That's not what i'm looking for. I just want the script to set "min" attr of "price_max" to current "value" of "price_min". And ONLY if the "min" of "price_max" is higher than it's "value" the last one should be changed.

Comment: @pringlesday Then we have to specify the initial value of "price_max" . At present in your code, it is showing me that the initial value of "price_max" is undefined. Please do check once.